# Responsive image that is fully visible

Tags: image, responsive

I have a header image that I would like to be 100% of the screen in width when the width of the screen is shorter than the height, and 100% of the screen in height when the height the screen is shorter than the width. Is there even a way that I could do this?

Edit-- some wanted all the relevant code, so here it is!

HTML

```
<div id="home-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/logo.png)" >
      <div class="caption">
        <h1 class="animated fadeInLeftBig">The *** Organization  </h1>
        <p class="animated fadeInRightBig">***</p>
        <a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="#rescue">***</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#home-slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  attachment: fixed;
  size: cover;
  repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;

}



#home-slider .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -104px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 15;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-size: contain;

}

#home-slider .caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  size: 72px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  vertical-align: center;

}





.caption .btn-start {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding:14px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #6e6d6c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.caption .btn-start:hover {
  color: #fff
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*  just in case if I want the image to be "parallax"
  background-attachment: fixed;
  */
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #6e6d6c;

}



.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

js

```
var slideHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#home .item').css('height',slideHeight);

    $(window).resize(function(){'use strict',
        $('#home .item').css('height',slideHeight);
    });

    $(function() {
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
if( width < height  ) {
        $('#home .item').css({width:'initial',height:height+'px'});
    }
    });

        var logoFix = function() {
              if( $(window).width() < $(window).height()  ) {
                $('.item').css('background-size','auto 100%');
              }
              else {
                $('.item').css('background-size','100%');
             }
        }
           $(function() {
             logoFix();
           });
```

Comment: Is this for a webpage? If so - are you using bootstrap/jquery/any other plugins?

Comment: It is a webpage, and I am using bootstrap and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You can detect screen resolution with

```
window.screen.availHeight    
window.screen.availWidth
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

You would then need to use JS to make a basic if statement to resize the image. (really basic example)

```
if (window.screen.availHeight > window.screen.availWidth){
height: 100%;
}

if (window.screen.availHeight > window.screen.availWidth){
width: 100%;
}
```

This is a very basic example and will definitely not work if you copy paste. It's just to give you an idea of what you have to do.

[Image sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)

Comment: Thanks! Using your link, I added: max-width: 100%; height: auto; and now I have a page in which, at least, my header is 100% in width when the width is shorter than the height. However, when I tried the other way around, with max-height: 100%; width: auto; it wouldn't do a thing. So, only part of what I want has been done. Is there any way that I could make the header image be 100% in height when the height is shorter than the width?

Comment: @Nora check for if statement https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

Turns out your image is a background of a . So, you can't directly resize that image. You have to play with the background properties of that  to achieve what you are after.

```
var logoFix = function() {
      if( $(window).width() < $(window).height()  ) {
        $('.item').css('background-size','auto 100%');
      }
      else {
        $('.item').css('background-size','100%'); 
     }  
}
   $(function() {
     logoFix();
   });
```

And if you want the logo size to respond to manual resizing of the window, add this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  logoFix();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! One of the previous answers that I got kind of answered my question but there was a problem with it, and I rand into the same thing with yours. The jQuery was the problem, but is there a way that I could do if (height < width) and my header image was not 100% at width this time, but transitioned into being 199% in height?

Comment: You mean, if (height<width && $('.header-image').width() < width) { $('.header-image').height('199%'); } ?

Comment: If you paste your code, it will be much easier to implement what you want to achieve, otherwise we are taking a stab in the dark and, so far, missing.

Comment: I pasted all relevant code... Also, when I tried to implement  if (height<width && $('.header-image').width() < width) { $('.header-image').height('199%'); } with the modifications that I made appropriate to my classes and divs, I lost the whole header section.

Comment: Turns out your image is a background of a `<div>`. So, you can't directly resize that image. You have to play with the background properties of that `<div>` to achieve what you are after. Edited above.

Comment: This time, the page showed the opposite: the image was 100% in height when the height was shorter than the width, but not 100% in width when the width was shorter.

Comment: Did you remove the above JS you provided in your question? Just replace what is in your <script> tags with what I pasted.

Comment: I edited javascript into my original post and, you can see that I edited your code in there. Thank you so much for being so patient with me, but it still doesn't work. The header image is 100% in width all the way through, even when the height is shorter than the width, and I want the header image to be width: auto; hieght: 100% when the height is shorter than the width, if that makes any sense. I tried changing some of your code so that its if auto 100% else 100% auto but then I got the opposite. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Just delete everything before `var logoFix = function() {` line.

Comment: Nothing changes